# PDF File is empty when reading file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I want to view (not download) on my frontend a file saved in my backend server.

Controller('documents') on my Nest app (Typescript) :

```
@Get(':id')
    async seeUploadedFiled(
        @Param('id') id:number,
        @Res() res
    ) {
        res.set({"Content-Type": "arraybuffer"})
        this.service.getDocument(id).then((response) => {
            return res.sendFile(response.path, {root: '.'})
        })
    }
```

service.getDocument(id) returns an object for which only the path is important here. The path is the path saved by DiskStorage (here : 'uploads/{file_name})

Fetcher in my React app (Typescript)

```
const handleVisu = (idDocument: number) => {
    client.get('/documents/' +idDocument, {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + loginToken}})
    .then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data)
      const blobFile = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'})
      const blobFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobFile)
      console.log(blobFileURL) //only for debugging

      window.open(blobFileURL)
    })
  }
```

Which is put inside a button "onClick". client is an axios instance.

I've tried a lot of "solutions" that I saw on other posts, and this is the one that seemed to function, but not on my app :

-I tried setting the responseType to 'application/pdf', for which it works on postman, but I still have a blank page on my react app.

-I tried setting the responseType to 'blob', and having the function

```
const handleVisu = (idDocument: number) => {
    client.get('/documents/' +idDocument, {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + loginToken}})
    .then((response) => {
      //console.log(response.data)
      const blobFile:Blob = response.data as Blob
      const blobFileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blobFile)
      console.log(blobFileURL) //only for debugging

      window.open(blobFileURL)
    })
  }
```

which returns a type error by saying that it cannot createObjectURL on that type

-I also tried by streaming files in my backend, but then I don't get anything on my frontend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay apparently putting the "Content-type" in the backend isn't enough, you need to put it in the frontend too :

```
const handleVisu = (idDocument: number) => {
    client.get('/documents/' +idDocument, {headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer " + loginToken}, responseType: "blob"})
    .then((response) => {
      const file = new Blob([response.data], {type: 'application/pdf'});
      const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);

      window.open(fileURL);
    })
  }
```

And that's it...